# Bombs - Cocos2d/Box2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a ball and a bomb. All I need to do is, when the ball collides with the bomb the bomb explodes pushing the ball away from the bomb in the opposite direction the ball was thrown in.

For instance, if the ball was thrown at a 45 degree angle and hits the bomb then, the bomb explodes and pushes the ball away from the bomb at a -45 degree angle.

Is that even possible? and if so could someone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Implement your own b2ContactListener to find the bomb-ball collision. Then apply linear impulse to the ball according to it's and bomb positions.

Comment: I have a b2ContactListener but I cannot find anything for linear impulse

Comment: there is a method ApplyLinearImpulse of b2Body

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abandon the physics simulation altogether (which is pretty much what you wrote) then you can either just not use Box2D or you can use it only for collision detection.

To use it only for collision detection you just set your bodies as sensors and when a collision is detected you send it off at the angle you would like (subtract or add angles together, rolling over when the maximum of a range is met).

If you would like to use the physics simulation (makes much more sense to me) then just set them both with the correct masks to collide with each other and set up your restitution (bounciness) as you would like it.  It sounds like you may want your ball to be a dynamic object and your bomb to be a static (I think that is what they call it).

Obviously, in either case you are going to need to set up any animations or particle emitters to trigger on collision.

Comment: I still want to use Box2D for my app. All I am saying is when the ball collides with the bomb, the bomb is destroyed, and which ever angle the player "flicked" the ball in at the bomb, the ball goes the opposite direction. E.G. ball was "flicked" at a 45 degree angle towards the bomb, the bomb explodes forcing the ball in a -45 degree angle (basically if they flick the ball to the right at the bomb and the ball hits the bomb, then the bomb forces it to the left)

Comment: Well if you want the full physics simulation then you don't need to worry about the 45 degree angle aspect (or whatever angle).  Just make the bomb either have very large mass or set it as a static object.  Actually that isn't really even necessary but you may want to tweak these things to get collision reactions the way you want them.  You just remove the bomb body after you are done stepping through the collisions and the ball will bounce off in the proper direction on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

When the ball and the bomb collide, instead of applying linear impulse to the ball, you can try enlarging the bomb's size for a very short time. After enlarging the bomb's size you can destroy the bomb body.

Enlarged bomb body would push the ball in proper direction.